# a lightweight intellect means 1. knowledge of small amount or 2. a person has a small knowledge or 3. both?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> a lightweight intellect

The phrase above gives some confustion and wonder what it's used generally for?

It looks like having two meanings: 1. knowledge of small amount or 2. a person who has a small knowledge

Does it mean 1 or 2 or both?

Comment: A person of lightweight intellect has low intelligence or ability to understand things. This is different from 'knowledge'.

Comment: Thx. The question is shortly: 1. intelligence itself or person with intelligence

Comment: Could be either. Difficult to say without further context. (1) Persons: I am surrounded by lightweight intellects! (2) Personal quality: John has a lightweight intellect; John is a person of lightweight intellect.

Comment: I don't know why this has been flagged for closure - it's a question about meaning of a phrase that could have an idiomatic meaning beyond what dictionary definitions of the individual words could convey. And they've included two things that they think it *might* mean, so they've at least done a degree of research.

Comment: Needs context: what was written before that phrase? It could be a euphemism for a slow-witted (foolish/stupid) person or it could be saying that someone  fancies themself to be an intellectual when in actual fact they are not.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, respect your opinion but sometimes we can appreciate some phrases like this without context and come to discuss more open-endedly and there is a degree of reseach showing two possible meanings.

Comment: I agree with @Mari-LouA here. If we knew the context especially the rest of the sentence preceding this phrase we might be better able to help disambiguate it.

Comment: Sorry but in English there's a saying "Context is king" which means  nearly every idiomatic phrase is ambiguous withoit its context. What's so difficult about writing a complete sentence, especially one that led you to ask the question in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Lightweight" is a sporting analogy, used in several sports but perhaps most famously in *boxing*. In certain sports, contestants compete against others in their own weight range, "lightweight" being the lightest group in a range that includes welterweight, mediumweight and heavyweight.

Outside of sports, the term is often used pejoratively, to suggest that someone is weak at, or at the very lowest level of something. For example, someone who gets intoxicated very easily from small amounts of alcohol is sometimes colloquially called a "lightweight" because they cannot 'compete' with heavy drinkers.

I would understand a "lightweight intellect" to mean someone who is not particularly intelligent - not necessarily lacking in a specific field, but generally - and who could not 'compete' intellectually with someone of above-average intelligence.

Comment: I have heard 'lightweight intellect' used by individuals about their rivals or critics, often in situations where an outside or disinterested observer would see little difference.

Comment: It is, essentially, an opinion.